# How do I call `count()` when testing my pallets `CountedStorageMap`?

Tags: pallet, storage, testing

I'm using a [CountedStorageMap](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.CountedStorageMap.html) in my custom pallet to store a map of created `Thing`s.

```
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn things)]
pub type Things<T> = CountedStorageMap<Hasher = Blake2_128Concat, Key = u64, Value = Thing<T>>;
```

I'm able to call the getter, `things(THING_ID)`, fine in my tests.

`let _ = ThingsModule::things(THING_ID);`

How do I call the `count` function on my pallet to assert stored totals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `count` function is on the `Things<T>` type so:

```rust
let count = Things::<T>::count();
```

Also note that:

```rust
let _ = ThingsModule::things(THING_ID);
```

is the same as:

```rust
let _ = Things::<T>::get();
```

And IMO the second syntax is preferable as it is easier to audit the different uses of `Things<T>`, versus some simple getter function which hides that behind some macro magic.